# REST и грамотная отправка команды/действия

Tags: json, rest

Рассмотрим следующую ситуацию: необходимо послать команду, не связанную с CRUD, пусть это "connect", "disconnect" к какому-то внешнему ресурсу, заранее известному и в самой команде не передающемуся. Тело команды содержит id и type получателя, который должен будет выполнить поступившую команду. Какой вариант с точки зрения идеологии REST будет правильнее:

```
1) GET: .../command?opcode=connect&id=100&type=1
2) GET: .../{type}/{id}?opcode=connect
3) POST: .../command RequestBody:{opcode:'connect', id:'100', type:'1'} 
4) POST: .../connect RequestBody:{id:'100', type:'1'} 
5) PUT: .../command RequestBody:{opcode:'connect', id:'100', type:'1'}    
6) PUT: .../connect RequestBody:{id:'100', type:'1'}    
7) Еще что-то
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это не просто операция чтения, то `GET` здесь быть не может.

Если запрос можно безопасно послать несколько раз, то метод должен быть `PUT` (обновить поле в модели -- можно выполнить несколько раз).

Иначе, если безопасно выполнить запрос несколько раз нельзя, то используется метод `POST`.

Я бы сделал так, если речь идёт о создании соединения:

```
POST /resources/100/connections {type: '1'}
```

Правда, непонятно, что есть resources.

Если эти соединения привязаны к текущему пользователю, к текущей сессии, то я бы сделал так:

```
POST /session/jobs {id: 100, code: 'connect', type: '1'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы просто выкинул из головы CRUD-REST и использовал POST, как метод, подходящий для таких действий по умолчанию, т.е. это будет просто POST-запрос, возвращающий такой же ответ, как и остальные методы, просто он будет отличаться обработкой. На всякий заглянул на [первый попавшийся апи](https://developers.digitalocean.com/#shutdown-a-droplet) - там тоже используется POST для запуска действий.
Можно, конечно, использовать собственный метод типа EXEC, но есть возможность огрести от какого-нибудь чересчур приставучего прокси или запутать будущих девелоперов.